# about comparator in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, equals

what's different between the two?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var a = printName("Jennie")
    var b = printName("Jennie")
    println(a == b)     // compiler : false

    var c = "Robert"
    var d = "Robert"
    println(c == d)     // compiler : true
}

class printName(val name : String)
```

when I use the class, the result is `false` even if the String type is the same. but if I don't use class, then what happens is `true`.

Comment: Your class doesn’t override `equals`, string does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `class`, you must override `equals` and `hashcode`. But you can also use `data class` if you want to compare objects as `equals` and `hashcode` is already handled in `data class`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `c` and `d` are references to the same `String` instance.  (The compiler sees that the two string literals are the same, and merges them.)  But even if they were different `String` instances, they'd still compare as equal.  That's because [`==`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#structural-equality) calls the [`equals()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/equals.html) method, and `String` overrides that to return true if the two strings have the same characters.

In your first case, `a` and `b` are references to different `printName`<sup>*</sup> instances.  (`printName()` is a call to its constructor, so each call returns a new instance.)  And your `printName` class does *not* override [`equals()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/equals.html), so it inherits the default implementation from its superclass (`Any`).  And that implementation always returns false for different instances, regardless of whether their contents are the same.

If you want different `printName` instances to compare as equal if they have the same contents, then you should override its `equals()` method.  You could do that manually, e.g.:

```
class PrintName(val name: String) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?) = other is PrintName
                                    && name == other.name
}
```

Or you could make it a [`data class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), which does that automatically.  (It also adds `toString()` and several other useful methods, but has some restrictions around constructors and inheritance.)

Another option might be to share or cache `printName`s instead of creating a new one each time.

---

<sup>(* By the way, it's conventional to use class names that start with a capital letter, so they stand out.)</sup>